# Submit function not working after showing a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working on a donation form where we are trying to create a popup to encourage people to give monthly instead of one-time. The logic is as follows:

1. User submits donation form
2. If the monthly donation checkbox is selected, the popup doesn't show
3. If the monthly donation checkbox is not selected, it checks the amount of the donation
4. If the gift is above $500, the popup is not shown and the form is submitted through a function called submitForm(). This works perfectly.
5. The popup is shown to all other users. It includes two buttons, one to change their gift to a monthly one and the other to submit their donation as a one-time gift as they originally entered it.
6. If the user selects that they don't want to make their gift monthly the submitForm() function is called.
7. If the user selects that they do want to make their gift monthly the code changes the form so that the monthly checkbox is selected and the amount changes to a lower amount. Then the submitForm() function is called.

The problem I'm having is that the submitForm() function will work if the amount is above $500 with no problems. However, if the popup is shown to the user the form will not submit. It closes the popup window and seems to reload the page but does not actually submit the form. Does anyone know why this would be happening? Just an FYI, I have not done any styling to the popup, right now I was just trying to get the buttons to work.

The form can be found here: http://support.ddfl.org/site/Donation2?df_id=9562&mfc_pref=T&9562.donation=form1

**Note, you do not need to make a donation to test the form. Enter an amount and press the donate button. After walking through the steps above, it should try to submit the form and inform you that you have not filled out required fields to process the form.**

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();

var amount;
var monthlyDonation;

jQuery('#ProcessForm').submit(function(event){

     //Check if monthly donation box is checked - if not prevent submit
     if(document.getElementById('level_standardauto_repeatname').checked == false){
          event.preventDefault();

          var actualVal = jQuery('input[name=level_standardexpanded]:checked').attr('id');

          if(actualVal=="level_standardexpanded11710"){
               amount = 1000;
          } else if(actualVal=="level_standardexpanded11711"){
               amount = 500;
          } else if(actualVal=="level_standardexpanded11712"){
               amount = 250;
          } else if(actualVal=="level_standardexpanded11704"){
               amount = 100;
          } else if(actualVal=="level_standardexpanded11713"){
               amount = 55;
          } else if(actualVal=="level_standardexpanded11714"){
               amount = 35;
          } else{
               amount = document.getElementById('level_standardexpanded11703amount').value;
          }        


          //If amount is greater than 500 do not show lightbox and submit form
          if(amount>=500){          
               submitForm();
          }
          //If amount is between 400 and 499.99 show lightbox - make monthly gift 75
          if(amount>=400 && amount<= 499.99){
               monthlyDonation = 75;
               showLightbox(monthlyDonation);
          }
          //If amount is between 200 and 399.99 show lightbox - make monthly gift 50
          if(amount>=200 && amount<=399.99){
               monthlyDonation = 50;
               showLightbox(monthlyDonation);
          }
          //If amount is between 100 and 199.99 show lightbox - make monthly gift 35
          if(amount>=100 && amount<=199.99){
               monthlyDonation = 35;
               showLightbox(monthlyDonation);
          }
          //If amount is between 50 and 99.99 show lightbox - make monthly gift 20
          if(amount>=50 && amount<=99.99){
               monthlyDonation = 20;
               showLightbox(monthlyDonation);
          }
          //If amount is between 20 and 49.99 show lightbox - make monthly gift 10
          if(amount>=20 && amount<=49.99){
               monthlyDonation = 10;
               showLightbox(monthlyDonation);
          }
          //If amount is below 19.99 show lightbox - make monthly gift 5
          if(amount<=19.99){
               monthlyDonation = 5;
               showLightbox(monthlyDonation);
          }

     }
});




function showLightbox(newGift){
     jQuery.colorbox({
          html:"<div class='monthlyUpsellLightbox' style='width:400px; height:200px;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #000;'><h1>Old gift amount is " + amount + "<br/>New gift amount would be " + newGift + " each month</h1><div>Do you want to make your gift a monthly donation?</div><button id='noButton' onclick='noChange()'>I do not want to make my gift monthly.</button><button id='yesButton' onclick='changeAmount()'>Yes, make my gift monthly.</button></div>"
     });
}


function noChange(){
     jQuery.colorbox.close();
     submitForm();
}


function changeAmount(){
     //Change the amount of donation field
     document.getElementById('level_standardexpanded11703amount').value = monthlyDonation;

     //Check donation field radio button
     document.getElementById('level_standardexpanded11703').checked = true;


     //Set monthly checkbox to be checked
     document.getElementById('level_standardauto_repeatname').checked = true;

     jQuery.colorbox.close();

     submitForm();

}

function submitForm(){
     console.log("submit form reached");
     document.getElementById('ProcessForm').submit();
}




</script>
```

I'm very new to web development so I appreciate any advice you can give! Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: It submitted the form for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by triggering a click event for the submit button instead of calling submit on the form. The below code:

```
function submitForm(){
  document.getElementById('ProcessForm').submit();
}
```

Was changed to:

```
function submitForm(){
  document.getElementById('pstep_finish').click();
}
```

Thank you everyone for your help! :)